# property of singular measure with respect to Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, singular-measures

Question: Let $\mu$ be a finite positive Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ that is singular to Lebesgue measure. Show that 
$$\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{\mu([x-r,x+r])}{2r}=+\infty$$
for $\mu$-almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

By Folland Theorem 3.22, I know that the set of these $x$ is $m$-null, but I don't know why it is $\mu$-a.e.

Comment: This is a theorem in Rudin's RCA. Look at the chapter on differentiation of measures.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just read Folland but not Rudin, so this problem is quite hard for me.